# ПрЕдира или прИдира?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно написать, прЕдира или прИдира? ПрЕдирчивый или прИдирчевый? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 8):

ПрИдира. ПрИдирчИвый.  Приставка при-, суффикс прилагательного -чив-.